# jQuery queue not working

Tags: jquery

What I am trying to do is to clear the html on a page, insert a single div, give it a backgound image, fade it in, keep it there for a few seconds, fade it out and then return to the previous html. I'm doing this:

```
var body_html = $('body').html();

    $('body').queue(function(){
      $(this).empty().css('background-image','none').html('<div class="start-img"></div>');
      $(this).dequeue();
    }).queue(function(){
      $('.start-img').html('<img src="'+url+'public/img/holding.jpg">').fadeIn(1000).delay(10000).fadeOut(500);
      $('.start-img').dequeue();
    }).queue(function(){
      $(this).html(body_html).css('background-image','url("../img/paper-bg.jpg")');
      $(this).dequeue();
    });
```

I have spent a ridiculous amount of time googling but this seems to match the examples I've seen and it doesn't work. Firebug shows no errors. What happens is the page goes blank and the background image (holding.jpg) fades in for about one second, then fades to a blank page. When I view the generated source, only the div.start-img is present as html.

I've never used queue() before and I must have misunderstood it but can anyone set me right? Even if there is a better way of doing it, why does my code not work?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert with jQuery's [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) method. (I've never used it before.) But I think I spot a couple problems here:

**1. Dequeue events must be paired with same targets as the initiating queue event**

So in step 2, the line:

```
$('.start-img').dequeue();
```

Should be:

```
$(this).dequeue();
```

**2. You're treating asynchronous events as if they were synchronous**

Again in step 2: you have a `fadeIn` effect chained to a long delay chained to a `fadeOut` effect. This is going to take some time to complete. But the next line, the `dequeue` call, is going to execute immediately, which I expect will immediately move the queue to the next step and wreck havoc on your sequence.

**Solution**

Wait until any asynchronous events have completed before making the `dequeue` call to move on to the next queue event.

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates a sequence of steps like that which you describe in your question: http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/wg4jqdjs/

Here's the queue code:

```
var $newDiv = $('<div />').html('<h4>new block</h4>').hide();

$body
  .queue(function() {
    $body.children().fadeOut(1000, function(){ $body.dequeue(); });  
  })
  .queue(function() {
    $body.append($newDiv);
    $newDiv.fadeIn(1000, function(){ $body.dequeue(); });
  })
  .queue(function() {
    $newDiv.animate({backgroundColor: "red"}, 1500, function(){ $body.dequeue(); });
  })
  .queue(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ $body.dequeue(); }, 2000);
  })
  .queue(function() {
    $newDiv.fadeOut(1000, function(){ $body.dequeue(); });
  })
  .queue(function() {
    $body.find('h4:eq(0)').fadeIn(1000, function(){ $body.dequeue(); });
  });
```

Notice how the `dequeue` calls are made in the on-completion callbacks of the various asynchronous events.

---

**Addendum**

It would have been a little cleaner to have just passed the `dequeue` call to the various effect callbacks, like this:

```
$body.children().fadeOut(1000, $body.dequeue);
```

But, unfortunately, that was raising an error in my fiddle.

Comment: Thanks so much for this advice. I'm definitely getting somewhere now because I tried this and it works. One problem, though, is when the method does not take a callback. In that case I chained each() and that does take a callback. Seemed to work but is that the correct way?     The other thing is that I would like one queue element to do a repeating sequence (setInterval) before moving on so how could I code that in?

Comment: I've updated my fiddle to demonstrate how `setInterval` would work: http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/wg4jqdjs/8/. You need a terminating condition. I'd have to see a concrete example for the chained `each` case, either in a fiddle or perhaps as a new question.

Comment: The `.dequeue()` method was exactly what I needed! Much appreciated.